# How to yield item from RFPDupeFilter or CustomFiler

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I'm using Scrapy to crawl pages from different websites. With every `scrapy.Request()` I set some meta data which is used to yield an item. It's also possible that my code yields multiple `scrapy.Request()` for same url however with different meta.

```
yield scrapy.Request(url='http://www.example.com', meta={'some_field': 'some_value'} ..)
```

Now I can set `dont_filter=True` and scrapy won't block the duplicate request.

```
yield scrapy.Request(url='http://www.example.com', meta={'some_other_field': 'some_other_value'}, dont_filter=True, ..)
```

However, since for duplicate requests I'm only interested in metadata set on `scrapy.Request()`, I want to yield an Item from `RFPDupeFilter` or `CustomDupFilter`  so it will be written to JSON by the item pipeline.

```python
    class CustomDupFilter(BaseDupeFilter):

        def request_seen(self, request: Request) -> bool:
            fp = self.request_fingerprint(request)
            if fp in self.fingerprints:
                yield request.meta['some_other_value'] # yield metadata as Item
                self.fingerprints.add(fp)
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can yield items in Dupefilter, but I think one way around this is to disable the Filter and handle duplicate requests in custom spider middleware. Maybe something like this:

```py
class DupeFilterMiddleware:
    seen_requests = set()

    def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
        for output in result:
            if isinstance(output, scrapy.Request) and fingerprint(output) in self.seen_requests:
                # yield from meta
            elif isinstance(output, scrapy.Request):
                self.seen_requests.add(fingerprint(output))
                yield output
            else:
                yield output
```

Comment: Thanks @zaki98,  with few modifications I was able to implement your code for my need.

Comment: Hi @zaki98, I've another problem here. I always have HTTP_CACHE enabled. So if a request is cached, we will always have it saved into cache dir. Is it possible to implement HTTP_CACHE based DupFilter?